# Horizontally stretch a Grid inside a StackPanel with Vertical orientation

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I'm trying to make the Grids in this sidebar fill the sidebar which is a stack panel.  According  to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53977945/grid-doesnt-stretch-inside-stackpanel) this cannot be done.

My scenario is slightly different as I actually have a ListView with the StackPanel as the ItemsContainer.

I knocked up a quick example to demonstrate:

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MyList = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  Background="Orange" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5"                                    
                               Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

What's the best approach to take here? I want the menu items to bind to a dynamic list and stretch horizontally.  I also wish to avoid hard coding a number of RowDefinitions in a Grid instead of using a StackPanel.  Is it possible?

Many thanks

Comment: in your datatemplate set the background of the grid instead of the textblock. that should help

Comment: Thanks for spotting that.  I've updated the question, the same issue still occurs.

Comment: see answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the HorizontalContentAlignment to strech
its default behaviour is to cramble everything up on the left side:

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid  Background="Orange">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Background="Yellow"></StackPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
```

[image]

Ps. consider using an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List<String>` in case younplane to update these elements using MVVM